# Return flash message if duplicate id on database

Tags: laravel, controller

I want to create if else on controller laravel. if no error on database, data insert and return flash message success, and if have error on database (duplicate id) return error message i use laravel 5.3

This is exactly what I want

its my code

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to learn about [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and how to [format your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: You have to try create function and object data ; create object then save this data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do `try-catch` with `DB Transaction`

```
try {
    DB::beginTransaction();

    // your code
    // redirect with success message

    DB::commit();
}catch (Exception $e) {

    DB::rollback();

    // other actions
    // redirect with error message

}
```

Comment: have to use this? Illuminate\Database\QueryException

Comment: write your code into `try` and redirect with success message. write redirect with an error message into the `catch` section

Comment: oh its work but my catch like this ( catch(\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $ex) )